# How to access master page controls of master page from child page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have three master pages and i want to access control of last master page from child page but it is showing error of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" because the value is coming null. i don't what is the problem the same code i used earlier and it works but not this time may be confused to which master page to access.

Code which i used to access on child page :

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl li = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)this.Page.Master.FindControl("liCampDetails");
        li.Attributes.Add("class", "active");
```

Comment: your example is unrelated to your question. what is it you want to achieve and what have you tried? what code returns `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` ?

Comment: liCampDetails is control available  in your master page ?

Comment: if `li.Attributes.Add("class", "active");` returns the error, then it seems that the search for the control fails. that has nothing to do with accessing masterpage properties

Comment: Yes manish licampdetails is the control available in master page

Comment: ted i know search for the control fails because i used the debugger then the li returns null that's why I'm here because same code I've used earlier but it works.